# How to resolve "ErrorException in VerifyCsrfToken.php" in Laravel

Tags: php, caching, laravel, middleware

This is was my approach:

I run the following **PHP Artisan** commands:

```
php artisan make:middleware AfterCacheMiddleware

php artisan make:middleware BeforeCacheMiddleware
```

Then, I updated my newly created middlewares (**`AfterCacheMiddleware`** and **`BeforeCacheMiddleware`**) as shown below:

***AfterCacheMiddleware***

```
class AfterCacheMiddleware  {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request);

        $key = $this->keygen($request->url());

        if( ! Cache::has( $key ) ) Cache::put( $key, $response->getContent(), 1 );

        return $response;       
    }

    protected function keygen( $url )
    {
        return 'route_' . Str::slug( $url );
    }
}
```

***BeforeCacheMiddleware***

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Cache;
use Str;

class BeforeCacheMiddleware {

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $key = $this->keygen($request->url());

        if( Cache::has( $key ) ) return Cache::get( $key );

        return $next($request);
    }

    protected function keygen( $url )
    {
        return 'route_' . Str::slug( $url );
    }
}
```

Further, I've registered both middlewares in my **`app/Http/Kernel.php`**

```
'App\Http\Middleware\AfterCacheMiddleware',
'App\Http\Middleware\BeforeCacheMiddleware',

'cacheafter' => 'App\Http\Middleware\AfterCacheMiddleware',
'cachebefore' => 'App\Http\Middleware\BeforeCacheMiddleware',
```

Below is my route:

```
Route::get('middle', ['middleware' => 'cachebefore','cacheafter', function()
{
    echo "success";
}]);
```

On a first page load, everything is normal *(because the page does not get cached)*.

On a subsequent access, I get this error: ***`ErrorException in VerifyCsrfToken.php line 76: Trying to get property of non-object`***.

I think the error originates from this line:

**`if( Cache::has( $key ) ) return Cache::get( $key );`**

but I can't figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of adding all these things. These are good to have, if you want to update the header info too.

In your beforecacheiddleware:

`if( Cache::has( $key ) ) return Cache::get( $key );`

Change the above code as suggested by @Den

```
 if( Cache::has( $key ) ) 
 { 
     $content=Cache::get( $key );
     return response($content);
}
```

This will work. Revert Back if you have any issue.

Answer (score 1):

Try it.

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Event;

class AfterCacheMiddleware {

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{

       /* Event::listen('illuminate.query', function($query)
        {

            var_dump($query);

            return false;
        });*/

        $response = $next($request);

        $key = $this->keygen($request->url());
        $key2 = $this->keygen($request->url()).'_2';

        if( ! Cache::has( $key ) )
        {  

            Cache::put( $key, $response->getContent(), 1 );

            Cache::put( $key2, $response->headers, 1);
        }

        return $next($request);
}

    protected function keygen( $url )
    {
        return 'route_' . Str::slug( $url );
    }

}



<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Cache;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

class BeforeCacheMiddleware {

/**
 * Handle an incoming request.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Closure  $next
 * @return mixed
 */
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {

        $key = $this->keygen($request->url());
        $key2 = $this->keygen($request->url()).'_2';

        if( Cache::has( $key )&& Cache::has( $key2 ) ) 
        { 
            $content=Cache::get( $key );
            $header=Cache::get( $key2 );

            $header=explode('Cache-Control:',$header);
            $header1=explode('Content-Type:',$header[1]);
            $header2=explode('Date:',$header1[1]);
            $header3=explode('Set-Cookie:',$header2[1]);

            $CacheControl=trim($header1[0]);
            $ContentType=trim($header2[0]);
            $Date=trim($header3[0]);
            $SetCookie=trim($header3[1]);

            return response($content)
                    ->header('Cache-Control',$CacheControl)
                    ->header('Content-Type',$ContentType)
                    ->header('Date',$Date)
                    ->header('Set-Cookie',$SetCookie);

        }


        return $next($request);
    }

    protected function keygen( $url )
    {
        return 'route_' . Str::slug( $url );
    }

}
```